# How to take a string and have it as a variable...? I don't even know how to word this

Tags: java, string, methods, calendar, arguments

It's part of a bigger program, but I'm stuck on this concept.

```
public static void mod (String a)
{
    date.set(Calendar.a, 1  );
}
```

I want the method above to take in strings, so that it can work for DAY_OF_MONTH, YEAR, MONTH, etc etc. Like shown in main method below:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
    {
            mod("DAY_OF_MONTH");
            mod("YEAR");
    }
```

EDIT: There's missing initiations of "date" and etc but that's because I just took it from a bigger code. I'm stuck just on this *concept*.
**The problem is that I can't even compile,**
because there's an error with the " Calendar.a "

Comment: will look that up. havent learned it yet. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can `switch` the `String` and code each section separately. From what you need to do the `mod` should look something like

```
public static void mod (String a)
{
    switch(a){
        case "DAY_OF_MONTH":
            date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1  );
            break;
        /* and so forth for the other cases you want to handle */
}
```

The other possible solution is to write a function that would assign a `String` (in the same way) a `static int` with the flag required for `set` (i.e. `"DAY_OF_MONTH" -> Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` and so on)

Answer (score 2):

A certain D'oh is in order :)

Your function should be

```
public static void mod(int a) {
  date.set(a, 1); //Not sure where this date variable is from
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  mod(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  mod(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
}
```

If you look at the docs -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

The fields are all integers so you can just refer to the field as `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` and that passes as an int argument not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `Map<String, Integer>` to store the String value associated with the field.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = ....
map.put("DAY_OF_MONTH", Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

and then do :

```
public static void mod (String a){
    date.set(map.get(a), 1);
}
```